# Combine several matrices into one

Tags: matlab, matrix

In my simple code :

```
%%EQ1
syms x p;
matSol=[];
pvec=[]
for p=-5:5 
    eqn = x - p*(x^2);
    S = solve(eqn, x);
    %%STOCK S VALUES
    vectSol=[0];
    for j=1:size(S) 
        vectSol(j)=S(j);
    end
    pvec(p+6)=p;
    matSol = [matSol; vectSol]; %% Error using vertcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
end
%PLOT
subplot(1,2,1); plot(pvec, matSol); xlabel('p'); ylabel('x');
title('Equation 1 : x - p x²');
hold on;

%%EQ2
%% same code works with 'eqn = p - x^2;'
```

Result if i remove equation 1
[image: Result of code without equation 1]

I have the error message : `Error using vertcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.`. On the website `Matlab Answers`, a guy explain "When you combine several matrices into one big matrix then the dimensions of the single matrices have to match. In your case they don't. Thats's what the error message says."

But I'm not strong on Matlab, i begin with this language. Specifically how i should proceed? These little lines of code works for other equations.

Comment: Just a comment to simplify your code. The inner loop is just converting a column vector of symbolic variables to a row vector of doubles. This can be achieved using `vectSol=double(S).'`

Comment: For your function `p - x^2`, did you realize that the solutions are not real? It's for example `vectSol =

   0.0000 + 2.2361i   0.0000 - 2.2361i` for p=-5. Is it intended to plot them at 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as a beginner, it is very important to understand what is happening and how you could debug such code yourself. Matlab has a very helpful feature, if you type in `dbstop if error` it will stop the code exactly where the error occurs.

Doing so you will notice, that `p=0` is a special case. There only one solution is found. As each row of a matrix must have the same number of elements, you can not insert a row of one element into your matrix.

I don't know what you further want to do with the data, but a cell array might be helpful to solve it, it can store vectors of different sizes.

Comment: I try to obtain two `Bifurcation diagram` with 'Equation 1 : x - p*x^2' and 'Equation 2 : p - x^2' but between -5 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when `p = 0`, the equation `eqn = x - p*(x^2)` reduces to `eqn = x` which is linear in nature and `solve(*)` gives only the `one solution` which is `x = 0` Hence size of this solution is `1X1`. In all other cases of `p`, the equation is `quadratic` in nature giving `two solutions` where the sizes are `2X1`. Clearly, they can not be appended.

Depending on the situation, **as a quick fix**, you can specifically consider the case when `p = 0` or when `length(S)==1` and just append `S` with a `NaN` value.

The following code just after `S = solve(eqn, x);` will automatically append appropriate number of `NaN`s to `S`.

`S = [S; NaN(2-length(S),1)];% 2 is the degree of the equation (may need to be changed for other equations)`